# Do I need to reload files opened in sublime text after making a new branch?

Tags: git, sublimetext

If I have multiple files opened in sublime text and I am on the master branch.

Then I make a new branch while having files opened. Do I need to close the opened files later and reopen them when I create a new branch and switch on it?

Answer (score 1):

I think not, the editor will reload automatically. In other editor like vscode also like that, even have a branch switcher

Answer (score 1):

No. Depending on how you created the branch, the underlying system files might not change. Even if they do, Sublime should detect the change and update your view (unless you have unsaved changes, in which case it might alert you when you attempt to save the changes).

When you switch branches or apply commits (e.g. via a local merge, pull or rebase, etc) git will change the files in the working directory. Most text editors (and especially most code editors) will notice these changes and act appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not required. When ever you get a pull or change and branch or you are in a specific branch and when you get latest from master, in any of these cases it is not required to close and reopen your files. Your editor will take care of these changes. It is same as making changes to files on your disk and how your editor recognize them automatically.